# When can trapping be used?

Tags: disassembly, windows, binary-analysis, dll

This is the beginning of one of the functions inside NTDLL of Windows XP:

```
MOV EDI,EDI
PUSH EBP
MOV EBP,ESP
...
```

The book on reverse engineering I am reading(Eldad Eilam - Reversing: Secrets of Reverse Engineering) says this about the first line:

> It is essentially dead code that was put in place by the compiler as a
>   placeholder, in case someone wanted to trap this function. Trapping
>   means that some external component adds a JMP instruction that is used
>   as a notification whenever the trapped function is called.

Can you show me how exactly can trapping be used in practice? I assume that trapping is just calling a function with trapping instruction inside the other function, but I don't realize how the outside function can get "notified" about the call... Is it possible the author meant by "some external component" the debugger? It can make sense because if I set a breakpoint for some strange assembly insruction like `MOV EDI, EDI`, I'll get to where trapped function is...

Comment: Eldad Eilam - Reversing: Secrets of Reverse Engineering

Comment: @CuriousOne please edit the question with this info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mov edi, edi` is an instruction that is called hotpatch point

there are several articles about it on the internet, notable among them are:

1. [Raymond Chens old new thing 1](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110921-00/?p=9583)
2. [Raymond Chens old new thing 2](http://Raymond%20Chens%20old%20new%20thing]%20link%201)
3. [Johannas passing's Hot patch walkthrough](https://jpassing.com/2011/05/03/windows-hotpatching-a-walkthrough/)

The main utility for this instruction is to enable a third party app or Windows update to patch an existing function to a newer function  with minimal side effects when obscure race conditions become a reality  (hard patching any function with a detour will work most of the time or as raymond puts will work 99% of the time

quoting from the article linked

> The MOV EDI, EDI instruction is a two-byte NOP, which is just enough
>   space to patch in a jump instruction so that the function can be
>   updated on the fly. The intention is that the MOV EDI, EDI instruction
>   will be replaced with a two-byte JMP $-5 instruction to redirect
>   control to five bytes of patch space that comes immediately before the
>   start of the function. Five bytes is enough for a full jump
>   instruction, which can send control to the replacement function
>   installed somewhere else in the address space.

the `mov edi, edi` is used in conjunction with five space holders emitted by the compiler before the `mov edi, edi` like `0xcc` or `0x90`

so the patching software can patch in an atomically replaceable short jump and a long jump to a control area